# Java high CPU Threads | JBOSS EAP 6.3 | unable to get root cause

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss, cpu-usage

Help and guidance is highly appreciated.

The issue reported is of High CPU utilization (>95%) by JBOSS.

- JBOSS EAP 6.3 alpha is configured as a service through NSSM (https://nssm.cc) on windows server
- I have captured the thread dump and identified High CPU Utilizing threads (5 in all) which are as under :
  nativeId(in base 10 Decimal): 6428, 2768, 5904, 6100 and 6840. These threads are consuming around 15% 
  of CPU each.
- No deadlocks observed through thread dump
- I have not written the deployed code nor do i have the source code for these threads so i'm a bit stuck as part of the delivery/implementation team.

[High CPU threads identified through psexplorer.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDVN3.jpg)

- For these 5 threads, 2 types/variations of stack trace are there as under:

  http-/0.0.0.0:8080-187
  priority:6 - threadId:0x0000000022d29800 - nativeId:0x191c - nativeId (decimal):6428 - state:RUNNABLE
  stackTrace:
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
  at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Throwable.java:783)

  - locked <0x00000007b394a958> (a java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException)
    at java.lang.Throwable.(Throwable.java:310)
    at java.lang.Exception.(Exception.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException.(ExecutionException.java:92)
    at sun.nio.ch.CompletedFuture.get(CompletedFuture.java:78)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.readBytes(NioChannel.java:597)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.blockingRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:504)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill0(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:449)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.access$100(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:50)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$InputBufferImpl.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:438)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:357)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:193)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:999)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.close(MultipartStream.java:943)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.close(MultipartStream.java:922)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(IOUtils.java:280)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(IOUtils.java:223)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:123)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:347)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
    at com.newgen.wfdesktop.servlet.filehandler.processRequest(filehandler.java:70)
    at com.newgen.wfdesktop.servlet.filehandler.doPost(filehandler.java:122)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.newgen.ibps.security.xss.SECRequestValidator.doFilter(SECRequestValidator.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.newgen.wfdesktop.filter.WDSessionCheckFilter.doFilter(WDSessionCheckFilter.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.newgen.wfdesktop.filter.WDClickJackFilter.doFilter(WDClickJackFilter.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:420)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:353)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:911)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$ChannelProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:920)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Locked ownable synchronizers:
  - <0x000000069bcbde88> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

  http-/0.0.0.0:8080-146
  priority:6 - threadId:0x0000000024579000 - nativeId:0xad0 - nativeId (decimal):2768 - state:RUNNABLE
  stackTrace:
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
  at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Throwable.java:783)

  - locked <0x00000007b4558488> (a java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)
    at java.lang.Throwable.(Throwable.java:250)
    at java.lang.Exception.(Exception.java:54)
    at java.io.IOException.(IOException.java:47)
    at java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException.(ClosedChannelException.java:52)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:233)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.readBytes(NioChannel.java:597)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.blockingRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:504)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill0(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:449)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.access$100(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:50)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$InputBufferImpl.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:438)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:357)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:193)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:999)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.close(MultipartStream.java:943)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.close(MultipartStream.java:922)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(IOUtils.java:280)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(IOUtils.java:223)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:123)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:347)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
    at com.newgen.wfdesktop.servlet.filehandler.processRequest(filehandler.java:70)
    at com.newgen.wfdesktop.servlet.filehandler.doPost(filehandler.java:122)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.newgen.ibps.security.xss.SECRequestValidator.doFilter(SECRequestValidator.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.newgen.wfdesktop.filter.WDSessionCheckFilter.doFilter(WDSessionCheckFilter.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.newgen.wfdesktop.filter.WDClickJackFilter.doFilter(WDClickJackFilter.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:420)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:353)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:911)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$ChannelProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:920)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Locked ownable synchronizers:
  - <0x000000069a402d48> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

Answer (score 0):

`Hello`, so high cpu usage is not an issue per se. You need to take a series of thread dumps and analyze it either with `Samurai` or `fastthread.io`, the website.

`These threads are consuming around 15% of CPU each.` They might consume a high cpu but they are not blocked.